# JavaScript "class" has no properties

Tags: javascript

When I do

```
var classTest = Bar(myID);
classTest.Test();
```

while using the code below, it comes back and says `classTest has no properties`. I can't seem to read `classTest.id` either.

Doesn't work because "this" here apparently refers to Foo, not Bar.

```
Foo.prototype.Bar=function(id)
{
    var id = id;

    this.Test=function()
    {
        print("test");
    }
};
```

This doesn't work either.

```
Foo.prototype.Bar=function(id)
{
        var id = id;
};

Bar.Test=function() 
{
        print("test");
};
```

Neither does `Bar.prototype.Test=function(id);`

Neither does `Foo.prototype.Bar.prototype.Test=function(id);`

Comment: you didn't use the new operator, `classTest = new Bar(myID);`

Comment: What if I can't use the new operator? I was told I couldn't because in my actual code (not featured) I'm using an global instance of something and using new would screw that up.

Comment: Instead of being paranoid about not doing it, why not try it? `new` is the way to create objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I've tried it and I can't call my global's function if I use new. I can if I don't.

Comment: @Stradigos What's a definition of Bar we can use to reproduce this problem?

Comment: In Foo.prototype.Initialize() I'm doing this.myInstance = new WhatImInstancing. Bar needs to be able to use this.myInstance, but it can't if I instantiate Foo using new.

Comment: What is Bar? Does it need to be a class, can't it just be an object?

Comment: @AnotherDev EDIT: Bar will be used to create multiple Bar objects. Test needs to be a method.

Comment: @Axl There's plenty of people capable of writing good, readable, correct code in JavaScript, and JavaScript provides methods for them to do so. Whether other languages are better is not really on-topic for the question IMO.

Comment: This might help you get started with OOP in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Also it's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve with `Foo.prototype.Bar=function(id) ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't use classes like other OOP languages, but rater prototypes.

Anything within a "Class"'s prototype is available to all instances of that "Class", even if it's added after an instance of the "Class" has been created.

The "Class" itself is really just a function. But when called with the "new" operator, it will behave like a Class constructor from most other OOP's.

In each method on the "Class" and the constructor function there will be a keyword (`this`) that will be the handle to that instance.

```
var Bar = function() {
  // Im the constructor
}
Bar.prototype.setName = function(name) {
  // Im a method on the instances of Bar
  // We assing our property `name` with the value from my first argument
  this.name = name;
}
Bar.prototype.getName = function(name) {
  return this.name;
}

var bar = New Bar();
bar.setName('John');
console.log(bar.getName()); // John
```

---

This might not answer your question directly, but if you think long enough about it, it might answer it after all.

---

Inheritance in JavaScript is based on walking the "prototype chain". As odd as it seems, prototypes can have prototypes. When trying to access a property, the prototype will be checked. If the property isn't found in that prototype, then that prototype's prototype will be checked, and so on until there are no more prototypes. So, in order to create a "Subclass" that inharance the properties and method from it's "Superclass" you will have to do the following:

```
var Foo = function() {
  // Foo's constructor, remember to call your supers as well:
  Bar.call(this);
}
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype);
Foo.prototype.fooMethod = function() {
  return -1;
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.setName('John');
foo.getName(); // John
foo.fooMethod(); // -1
```

---

You can use what we learned above to create instances inside instances:

When we create an instance of Foo (`foo`), there will be created an instance of Bar (`foo.bar`):

```
var Bar = function() {
  // Im the constructor
}
Bar.prototype.setName = function(name) {
  // Im a method on the instances of Bar
  // We assing our property `name` with the value from my first argument
  this.name = name;
}
Bar.prototype.getName = function(name) {
  return this.name;
}

var Foo = function() {
    this.bar = new Bar();
}
var foo = new Foo();

foo.bar.setName('John');
console.log(foo.bar.getName()); // John
```

Comment: I've made this work myself, but apparently adding another another layer of objects makes this not work. For example, instead of you saying "var bar = function()" and "Bar.prototype.setName" this doesn't seem to work if you have to "Foo.prototype.Bar = function()" and "Foo.prototype.Bar.prototype.setName = function();

Comment: it works perfectly @Stradigos I don't know what is going on with your code

Comment: You want to reference an instance of `Bar` within an instance of `Foo`?

Comment: Are you trying to make Bar extend Foo and inharence the prototype?

Comment: @AnotherDev, Negative. I want to create an instance of Bar and call a method of Bar. But it has to be within Foo. I'm beginning to think this isn't possible and that I should just rethink my design...

Comment: "Foo.prototype.Bar = function()..." is implying that instances of Foo will have access to a property "Bar" that is a function (or in this case, a type). Is that what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: So, you're trying to have Foo instances contain an instance of Bar from which to call the method?

Comment: @Ixonal, Yes, essentially. In Foo.onEnter() I want to create a Bar object and then perform Bar.Test(); Being able to access Bar.id would be a bonus.

Comment: @Stradigos See the last part of my answer

Comment: This seems about right. Might want to expound more on why things are done this way, but otherwise good.

Comment: @Ixonal You are free to edit the post if you feel it could use some more textual info.

Comment: @dev-null Thanks, added some info. Hopefully it's not too long-winded.

Comment: What information are you trying to convey with *"FYI in Ecma6 there will be "real" Classes in JavaScript"* ? The class syntax is just syntactic sugar. I guess that's what you mean by "real" but I think that's more confusing than helping.

Comment: @FelixKling You are correct, OP stated earlier on that he was used to c++ and i figured that, that syntax would be more intuitive to him